# PostgreSQL SUM CASE expression with THEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, expression, case

I couldn't quite find what I was looking for while researching for an answer to my CASE expression issue. The purpose is to SUM count the occurrences of 'ACTIVE' accounts. However, after reviewing the results, there seems to be a set of parameters on an active account that I do not want to include in my SUM value. Here is the original SUM CASE:

```
 sum(
    CASE
        WHEN (type_txt = 'ACCOUNT'::text AND status = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS accounts_actv
```

However, I reworked the code to count for special circumstances when an active account should not be counted:

```
 sum(
    CASE
        WHEN (type_txt = 'ACCOUNT' AND status = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1
        WHEN (type_txt = 'ACCOUNT' AND status = 'ACTIVE' AND code = 483 AND open_date < CURRENT_DATE) THEN 0
        ELSE 0
    END) AS accounts_actv
```

I take it, the THEN 1 ELSE 0 cannot have a THEN condition with 0 ---- so I am trying to figure out how to not include this type of account in the SUM

Comment: `count(*) filter (where ....)` might be easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the additional condition in the same case:

```
sum(
    CASE
        WHEN 
            type_txt = 'ACCOUNT'::text 
            AND status = 'ACTIVE' 
            AND NOT (code = 483 AND open_date < CURRENT_DATE) 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS accounts_actv
```

Comment: Actually, once I looked it over, this didn't quite give me the results I wanted. Can you assist? The above result counted all items WHERE type = Account and status = active BUT DID NOT COUNT any situation in which type = account AND status = active AND code = 483 AND open_date < CURRENT_DATE......which is close. I thought the AND NOT() would require both conditions in order to not count but instead, it looks like it didn't count any records that had one or the other: code = 483 OR open_date < CURRENT_DATE. If a record doesn't meet both conditions at once, I want to count it. Thoughts?

Comment: When in doubt, check all possibilities. Please, look at [the example](https://rextester.com/CUG39936) and tell which ids have wrong results.

Comment: Your words of wisdom absolutely helped -- and seeing it in your example. I traced my issue to NULL values in the open_date table -- they were throwing off my count.

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` returns the value of the first (from top to bottom) `THEN` expression, that has a `WHEN` expression that evaluates to true (and `ELSE` if nothing matched). As your first `WHEN` is also true in the cases the second is true, the first is chosen and not the second. Always put the narrower `WHEN` before the less narrower ones in a `CASE`.

```
CASE
    WHEN (type_txt = 'ACCOUNT' AND status = 'ACTIVE' AND code = 483 AND open_date < CURRENT_DATE) THEN 0
    WHEN (type_txt = 'ACCOUNT' AND status = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you only sum 1, count(*) filter (where...) would be more elegant.

```
count(*) filter (
        where type_txt = 'ACCOUNT'::text 
        AND status = 'ACTIVE' 
        AND NOT (code = 483 AND open_date < CURRENT_DATE))
```